# Procedure Q can access **its** arguments [meaning of the "its"]

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Assume that procedure P calls procedure Q with n integral
> arguments, such that n > 6. Then the code for P must allocate a stack frame with
> enough storage for arguments 7 through n, as illustrated in Figure 3.25. It copies
> arguments 1–6 into the appropriate registers, and it puts arguments 7 through n
> onto the stack, with argument 7 at the top of the stack. When passing parameters
> on the stack, all data sizes are rounded up to be multiples of eight. With the
> arguments in place, the program can then execute a call instruction to transfer
> control to procedure Q. Procedure Q can access **its** arguments via registers and
> possibly from the stack.  -CS:APP

[image: stack frame]

I don't know what the 'its' refers to here, P's or Q's?

Comment: The general principle is if there are multiple *possible* referents for a pronoun (as *Peter fought Paul and broke **his** arm*) the "default" referent should be the "nearest" one - the one *most recently mentioned*. But there's often considerable flexibility here. In your cited example, ***its*** almost certainly means ***Q's*** on the basis of natural use of language -  but if *logically* that doesn't make sense you'll just have to assume the writer is either "careless, inconsiderate", or he takes it for granted the correct meaning is so obvious his ambiguous phrasing is simply not an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3 ambiguous pronouns by Justice Antonin Scalia.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42741/3-ambiguous-pronouns-by-justice-antonin-scalia) Also [What does the word 'it' refer to in the below sentence, and is there any ambiguity?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252144/what-does-the-word-it-refer-to-in-the-below-sentence-and-is-there-any-ambigui), and probably others.